# OrmLite LocalDate to DateTime Converter Not Being Applied On Where Clause For SqlLite In-Memory Db

Tags: c#, datetime, servicestack, ormlite-servicestack, nodatime

[Referenced Code](https://gist.github.com/WardenUnleashed/ca25d2ae44d9c8c3c33731e5c8ae5cad)

**Problem I'm Trying To Solve**

Make `ValuationsCommanderTests.SetTransactionAndRelatedEmbeddedDerivativevaluationsToBad_ValidInput_CorrectlyManipulatesDB()` pass.

**Attempts To Resolve Issue**

After debugging it, I have narrowed down the reason for it being unable to pass to be because of the private method `ValuationsCommander.SetRelatedDailyTransactionHistoryRecordsToBad` never updating records because of how it is converting(or rather not converting) NodaTime's `LocalDate` despite having registered a converter for this type.

An example of the SQL this method generates is the following

```
UPDATE "cfo_daily_trans_hist" SET "dh_sn_scenario_id"=@dh_sn_scenario_id 
WHERE (("dh_tq_tran_quote_id" = @0) AND ('Saturday, November 13, 1993' <= "dh_val_time_stamp"))
```

From this statement it would appear to me that the conversion from LocalDate to DateTime is not occurring and it has instead decided to compare it via toString rather than through a DateTime comparison.

Some of the things I have thought may be causing this are the following:

- Dialect Provider not properly registering the NodeTime Converter
- Creating the `DailyTransactionhistoryTableModel` with a dummy class that has `DateTime` as its type for `ValuationTimeStamp.`

Neither of those seem to be underlying issue, and I have run out of ideas of ways to resolve this.

Is there something I'm not understanding about how OrmLite utilizes the converter or anything else I might try to resolve this issue?

Comment: The time stamp has hours, minutes, seconds so you need to truncate to a whole date.  Second you should not have double quotes around the variable name dh_val_time_stamp

Comment: @jdweng That SQL statement is auto-generated by OrmLite which is the inherent problem. The LocalDate appears to be being converted to a string rather than the datetime pattern you are recommending.

Comment: You should also override `ToQuotedString()` for queries which emit the value in SQL. Also note that SQLite DateTime behavior differs based on the different .NET Framework or .NET Core ADO.NET Providers. You can check [SqliteDateTimeConverter.cs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.OrmLite/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.OrmLite.Sqlite/Converters/SqliteDateTimeConverter.cs) for a reference example of `DateTime` handling in OrmLite's SQLite DialectProvider.

Comment: @mythz Thank you! That was exactly the problem, for some reason this was working fine when we were running with the `SqlServer2012OrmLiteDialectProvider` which seemed to handle this problem without having `ToQuotedString()` implemented

Answer (score 3):

Credit goes to @mythz for solving this one, as per usual. :)

The problem ended up being an incomplete implementation of a LocalDate to DateTime OrmLiteConverter, by not implementing `ToQuotedString()` it was using the default string when emitting the value in SQL, as a result something to the effect of `Saturday, November 13, 1993` rather than a datetime format recognized by SQL.